# Upstash's Rate Limiter takes 5s to complete API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, redis

i'm trying to set up the upstash rate limiter on a GET route on my own NextJS API following web dev cody video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xqlkAPnoTY (which is basically the demo code on upstash's rate limiter repo).

This is my code without the limiter, takes around 50ms to complete :

```js
import Albums from "@models/albums";
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const GET = async () => {
    try {
        await connectToDB()

        const albums = await Albums.find({})

        return NextResponse.json(
            albums,
            { status: 200 }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return NextResponse.json(
            "Failed to fetch all ablums",
            { status: 500 }
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the code with upstash rate limiter added, which takes around 5s to complete :

```js
import Albums from "@models/albums";
import { connectToDB } from "@utils/database";

import { Ratelimit } from "@upstash/ratelimit";
import { Redis } from "@upstash/redis";

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

const ratelimit = new Ratelimit({
    redis: Redis.fromEnv(),
    limiter: Ratelimit.slidingWindow(1, "10 s")
})

export const GET = async (request) => {
    try {
        const ip = request.headers.get("x-forwarded-for") ?? "";
        const { success, reset } = await ratelimit.limit(ip);
        if (!success) {
            const now = Date.now();
            const retryAfter = Math.floor((reset - now) / 1000);
            return new NextResponse("Too Many Requests", {
                status: 429,
                headers: {
                    ["retry-after"]: `${retryAfter}`,
                },
            });
        }

        await connectToDB()

        const albums = await Albums.find({})

        return NextResponse.json(
            albums,
            { status: 200 }
        )
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return NextResponse.json(
            "Failed to fetch all ablums",
            { status: 500 }
        )
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea why it suddenly takes so long to complete API calls with the rate limiter set up ?

Comment: Can you try to increase the number of requests you allow in the window from 1 to something higher? What happens when you make it `Ratelimit.slidingWindow(10, "10 s")` for example?

Comment: @mdumandag i tried few different settings for the slidingWindow function already but none of them change anything. It seems like the limit doesnt even work because if i set up the rate limiter like this : Ratelimit.slidingWindow(1, "20 s") and send two requests in the span of less than 20s the requests are going through code 200 like it's not limiting at all